# conda install -c mlgill imutils

Tags: python-3.x, conda

the following command:

```
 conda install -c mlgill imutils
```

trouble while installing those packages with conda version 3.6. Is there any dependency on Conda version for those particular packages?

I was able to install it with python 3.6  using `pip install imutils` 
but with conda installation I'm getting errors.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: which kind of error it rises to you? can you share the error

Comment: if you are trying to install onto a Windows machine, the `imutils` package in the `mlgill` channel is only built for mac and linux.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Windows, use `conda install -c pjamesjoyce imutils` instead !